# Using WCF connection in Blazor .NET6 throwing error

Tags: wcf, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, reportingservices-2005, basichttpbinding

I want to use a WCF service into Blazor APP .NET6.
I added Connection Service using a .asmx service URL in the project.
But while running the Below Code
***new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()***,
facing a error as

```
var rsBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
rsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
rsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

**'The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelBindingUtility' threw an exception.'**

[Error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMbwu.png)

I want to use the WCF connection to render a SSRS Report URL on the Blazor Page

Comment: What are you trying to do? The tags contain tags of discontinued and conflicting products. WCF was never ported to .NET Core to begin with, SSRS 2005 went out of support over a decade ago, current versions use REST APIs, rendering is done on the *server*, *always* and only the HTML is returned to the browser. That output is available as an IFRAME too

Comment: The [SOAP API docs warn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-into-applications?view=sql-server-2016) that the SOAP API is deprecated since 2017 and the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/developer/rest-api?view=sql-server-2016) should be used instead. To get the HTML you can use [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-url-access-web-application?view=sql-server-2016). That's how the viewers work

Comment: Unfortunately, SSRS itself is essentially abandoned with essentially no new features since 2017. That's the reason there's not even an MVC viewer. For the last 6 years MS is pushing people to use Power BI. What was SSRS was repackaged as [Power BI Paginated Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi) with all new features going there.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. And Blazor network I/O is limited to specially configured HttpClient, so I think your implementation is less likely to succeed.